# Missing .obj file

Tags: import

I'm a first time user of Blender --

I've read the other posts on missing obj files.  I tried everything outlined in those posts and still unable to see, or locate the file?

I'm exporting from Formz - I've also tried an stl file.

If I create a cube and export it as a .obj - I'm able to locate the cube.

For the file that I'm unable to "see" I've also deleted many of the parts and still it can't be found.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Might be too large. Check the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html) to see whether the geometry is imported (there should be a new object). If so try to scale it up or down using `s` while selected. Otherwise please provide the file, preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: ...thank you for the feedback.  I tried uploading the file in question - but it did not upload the file - I waited for several hours and there was no movement?  I would like to get you the file to you -- is there another way - thank you, again

Comment: Go through the help pages: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help and try again, otherwise you can use anything else to share the file...

Comment: ...tried it again and it worked.  Would you like to see the .obj file? Thank you!